# Multinomial logistic regression for big data

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution, large-data

How do I go about doing a multinomial logistic regression when I have 70 million observations? Is it feasible? It seems that R is out of the question due to memory constraints?

Answer (score 1):

(1) This doesn't seem like a multinomial regression questions, but rather a "how to use R with a large dataset" question. There is nothing intrinsic about multinomial regression that restricts your number of observations.
(2) I would use a commercial package.
(3) Many others have used R successfully. I think this questions has already been addressed here a number of times:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055502/recommended-package-for-very-large-dataset-processing-and-machine-learning-in-r
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186077/work-in-r-with-very-large-data-set
...
http://www.r-bloggers.com/handling-large-datasets-in-r/

Comment: Good links, they introduced me to the series of `bigX` `R` packages. Looks like `biglm` will do the trick here (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html).